# Can php run code on server side without user request?

Tags: php, javascript, cron

Server 1 Pings/Request URL http://website.com/page.php?code=NeedThat

Server 2 "page.php" grabs "NeedThat" and execute img src or JavaScript on server side

Image Code on page.php

Thanks a lot forr the help got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing `gotit.php` is easy.  You just use curl or (if allowed) file_get_contents to download the image src.  For the JavaScript, you need to figure out what network requests that causes, then do them manually.

EDIT: If gotit needs to keep outputting that image, then you can have page.php parse the HTML, then do its own request to the resulting src (which will be website.com/sale.php...).

Comment: @Mark, your best bet is probably the built-in [DOM library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Start with [loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Comment: I was able to fix it thanks a lot! used file_get_contents with stream

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to run another script, file_get_contents can be filled out with the correct parameters and have the return value saved as such:

`$result = file_get_contents('http://location.com/page.php?code=' . $code);`

More advanced solutions can be crafter with something like curl, but for a simple request, file_get_contents should suffice.

Comment: @majiic bunnie ok so I got it like that now: Page.php `<?php
$result = file_get_contents('http://website.com/gotit.php?transid=' . $transid);
?>`  and gotit.php  `<?php
echo '<img src="http://website.com/sale.php?TotalCost=1&AffiliateID=<?php echo $transid?>" width="1" height="1" >';

?>` I ran once myself didn't seem to work

Comment: The first call on page.php looks okay, the second one on gotit.php has <?php echo $transid?> inside of an active php echo. You cannot do this, instead you should just: `<?php echo '<img src="http://website.com/sale.php?TotalCost=1&AffiliateID='.$transid.'" width="1" height="1" >'; ?>`

Comment: @magjiic bunnie changed that still no effect (I run from browser for testing) do I need to change file Permissions?

Comment: I was able to fix it thanks a lot! used file_get_contents with stream